# Установка KDE сверх LXDE Lubuntu

Tags: linux, kde, lubuntu, lxde

Каким образом можно установить KDE сверх LXDE на Lubuntu? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: `sudo apt full-upgrade` — это было лишнее IMHO.